# Jmeter: change default body data request filed with new value from json response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I call a REST web service with post method with this request:

```
{
    "id":null,
    "scrollType":0,
}
```

In JMeter after creating **Thread Group** and add **10 to Loop Count**, I added **Http Request**.I set **protocol** and **other stuff and body data**.

I added **JSR223 PostProcessor** and i'm using this **groovy** code to get **last id from my response**:

```
vars.put("id_BSH", new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).get(9).id as String)
```

Now i want to add `id_BSH` into next request instead of `"id":null,` !

How can i do this?

For **first** request I want to be `id = null` and in other request i want to be `id = ${id_BSH}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `id_BSH` variable in your request:

```
"id":${id_BSH},
```

You just need to initialize value with null, you can defined it in Test Plan or in a [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

> User Defined Variables element lets you define an initial set of variables, just as in the Test Plan